# using invocationCount in testng tests with Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I have a general test, call it

```
public void generalTest(boolean var1, boolean var2) {
   if (var1) {
      ...
   } else {
     ...
   }

   if (var2) {
     ...
   } else {
     ...
   }
}
```

I have a class level `int countNumber` initialized to 0;  Then I do this

```
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = "getEmptyPhone", invocationCount = 4)
public void test(TextContext context) {
    countNumber++;
    boolean v1 = countNumber < 3;
    boolean v2 = (countNumber % 2) == 0
    generalTest(v1, v2);
}
```

`countNumber` increases each time so I get a combination of all booleans.  The one thing is that the `dataProvider` is kind of complicated and it does a lot of soap messaging.  Once I run it, I can use the same data in the other three tests, but in the above the data provider is called each time.  Is there a way I can have it just do the data provider the first time?  I know I could just have one test and put like for (`boolean v : new boolean[] { true, false}`), but that way if the test fails, the later ones will not be executed.  Some tests could pass even if others didn't.  So is there a way to do this?

I suppose it would also be too much to ask also if I could use the "description" keyword, and make `countNumber` be part of it so the test failure would show which iteration?